# Angular-charts.js colors dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Do you know if it's possible to give a dynamically generated array of colors to our chart?

When i init my colors array with hex colors, it works, but if i give it the return of my "getRandomColor" function, it doesn't work at all.

Do you have any idea

```
$scope.theChart.colours = ["#78CBBC", "#CF207A", "#5DBA1A", "#3AEB06", "#CA5923", "#3C34E0", "#E14FCC"]; // works fine
```

--

```
$scope.theChart.colours = getcolors(); //doesn't work

function getcolors(array){
var colors = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    colors[i] = getRandomColor();
  }
  return colors;
}

  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You know your getcolors(array) function is missing the opening brace?  Your code appears to work as long as you make sure it's formatted properly.

Comment: Hmm only missing in my copy paste, my bad.

I mean, the code is giving me an array of colors (well formatted, via console.log) but chart.js seems to ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here:

```
function getcolors(array) { // <- missing {
```

Comment: Hmm my bad for the copy/paste. That bracket is in my code.